# how to test a code is working on production in Laravel using Pest?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, php-pest

I have a middleware in a Laravel project that triggers some alerts in sentry

```
$status = $response->status(); 
if ($status === 500 && config('app.env') === 'production') {            
   \Sentry\captureException(new \Exception('my message', $status));
}
```

In my test I have the following:

```
Saloon::fake([
    PostRequest::class => MockResponse::make(["message"=>"error"], 500),
]);

$this->postJson("/my_url", [
    'body' => 'test'
])->assertJson($response);

$exception = new \Exception('my message', 500);

$sentry = Mockery::mock(\Sentry\State\HubInterface::class);
$sentry->shouldReceive('captureException')->with($exception);
```

In my test coverage I can see that is not entering in the condition because tests are executed in the testing environment, what can I do?

Comment: Noooooooooooo, don't ever run tests on production, NEVER EVER!!!! you can mess up real data with fake data, etc, and use the production server resources and make the page slower or worse, that is not good for your customers!

Comment: @matiaslauriti He is not running tests on the production. He is explicitly saying that in the last line of the question. He just wants to simulate the behavior of production in the test environment

Comment: @MohammadhosseinFereydouni running tests ALWAYS sets `app.env` = `testing` even in `production`, so he did not state if he is running it on production or on a local environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the environment value at the beginning of the test with the `config()` function.

```
config(['app.env' => 'production'])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

**Note:** make sure this change DOES NOT trigger any actions outside of your test setup.

Comment: This should definitely come with a note that any external API calls that check for production configs may be affected when changing this and potentially affect production data.

Comment: Even though this works, you NEVER have to do this on a production server... never run tests and change `app.env` to something different than `production` on a production server. You can run stuff that should only run on an environment that is not production, messing up your data and other worse things...

Comment: @matiaslauriti He is running tests on his testing environment and just needs to simulate production behavior. Of course, running tests on the production server is not a good idea!

Comment: @MatthewBradley It is a test setup. This code has nothing to do with production data.